# Dockerfile for Qristal: what should be the value of $QB_DIR

Tags: quantum-computing, qristal-sdk

When cloning the [Qristal repository](https://github.com/qbrilliance/qristal) and trying to build the Docker image with `docker/Dockerfile`, what is an appropriate setting for `$QB_DIR` that is on line 27 of the Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR $QB_DIR
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the current public release, the default for `$QB_DIR` is `/mnt/qb`. In effect you can use any valid path inside your container image.